# "The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage" error for a generic method when return type is known

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

This little example cause a compile error:

```
public static class TestClass
{
    public static T Create<T>() where T : new()
    {
        return new T();
    }

    public static void Foo()
    {
        // The type arguments for method 'T TestClass.Create<T>()' cannot be inferred 
        // from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
        HttpClient client = Create(); 
    }
}
```

Is this how type inference is supposed to work? From what I can see it is rather obvious that `T` should be `HttpClient` in this case so that I do not need to specify it explicitly.

But perhaps the inference does not work with return type by design?

P.S. I do know how I can specify type explicitly, I am just trying to find out if there is a way to make the compiler find this out itself, or it's just how the compiler is designed

Comment: Sure, it could probably work like that (with more than a few rules), but it doesn't, you cant infer a generic parameter by what the method is assigned to. You'll have to do it the old fashioned way `Create<Bob>()`

Comment: [1/2] You need to write: `HttpClient client = Create<HttpClient>();`. Generic type parameters can be inferred when used as argumenrts, but there is a problem for returned types, espacially when a method has no parameters: the compiler is not able to know what to use even if assigning to a variable being of a type because it can be anything in the hierarchy.

Comment: [2/2] Therefore related: [Why downcasting is not allowed in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58728416/) • [How to create a new object instance of class being the same type of another instance by only knowing it as base class type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65913153/) • [Upcasting and downcasting in C#](http://people.cs.aau.dk/~normark/oop-csharp/html/notes/inheritance-note-up-down-casting.html) • [Upcast And Downcast Basics](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/upcast-and-downcast-basics)

Comment: @OlivierRogier Neither these links nor your [suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3917249/11683) are relevant (the duplicate is especially irrelevant because it shows assignment to `var`). Please see the [Eric Lippert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3204520/11683) for the actual explanation.

Comment: @GSerg You are right, but I don't know how I can remove the "wrong" duplicate. The first one does answer my question

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik You need to get a [gold C# badge owner](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/40/c-sharp) to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the information, there is still some way for me to go before I get one :)

Comment: It is not because we define a variable of a given type and that we assign it from the return of a generic method that the compiler can be able to say that it is an object of this type. Because it could be anything, how to know? How the compiler can know what's in our minds? Do I want to put a MyRootClass or a MyChildClass in a MyRootClass reference? The compiler asks for more details, like with LINQ's `TypeOf` or `Cast`. [Polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031273/#58197730) • [Generic polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58570948)

Comment: @OlivierRogier Like I said, polymorphism has nothing to do with it. It is not the choice between the possible parent-child classes that makes it impossible, and if it was only about the parent-child classes then it would not be a problem because the answer to that question is simply taking the specified type (you have specified `MyChildClass` as the return type, so *that* takes place of the `T`). Please see the [Eric Lippert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3204520/11683) for why it was decided to not implement this for generics (but was decided to implement it for lambdas).

Comment: I understand we would expect the compiler to choose for us from what is written but it can't do that, this will be too dangerous and hazardous, smelly and anti-pattern. And yes, it's all about inheritance and polymorphism, and thus castings. And here guess that we want to put in one type, this type and not another from the hierarchy, which is impossible to ensure for the compiler and the runtime, it would be a break in the OOP Theory. And what seems intuitive at first sight is finally and actually counterintuitive, because of the Theory itself.

Comment: @OlivierRogier I take it you have not consulted the [Eric Lippert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3204520/11683) that demonstrates this problem without resorting to inheritance and polymorphism, and then explains that it is *entirely possible*, but *extremely hard* to make the compiler deduce the correct type in this situation, so it was decided to not do it.

Comment: Of course, it would be very easy, very very easy, to decide to make the compiler do that: I want A, give my a A... But why not a B : A ? Thus that would be as explained, going against the OOP theory, a big break, an endless ravine, and that would make our applications insecure and unstable, difficult to maintain, and worse than that. Therefore .NET cannot accept such a thing.

Comment: @OlivierRogier If you read the actual [Eric Lippert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3204520/11683), you would learn that ".NET" (that is, C#, actually) absolutely can accept such a thing, it's just that it is extremely hard to implement it without errors. You would also learn that it *has been done* for lambdas. So what you are saying is that since the introduction of lambdas in C#, the C# applications have been insecure and unstable, and the entire LINQ concept should be removed because it is firmly based on this very type deduction that you are arguing against.

Comment: @OlivierRogier Please re-read the [Eric Lippert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3204520/11683) in full. He explains why `N(G(5))` doesn't work with generics, but `N(x=>x.Length)` does work with lambdas, even though it's the same problem of overload resolution with respect to available overloads of `N()`. He then proceeds to explain that it took him a year to make the `N(x=>x.Length)` work, and that it is [NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness) to make the `N(G(5))` work.